# Правильный JOIN для выборки из двух таблиц

Tags: mysql

запутался я в джойнах. Прошу помощи))
Короче, есть таблицы products и categories.
В первой лежат товары, у каждого есть свой product_id. Во второй лежат пары данных: "product_id (id товара)" - "category_id (id его рубрики)".
Есть также product_id одного конкретного товара.
Нужно вывести любые N товаров, находящихся в той же рубрике.
Помогите, пожалуйста, составить правильный SQL-запрос?

```
SELECT * FROM products pr 
LEFT JOIN categories pc ON (pc.product_id = '$product_id') 
GROUP BY pc.category_id 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Comment: какие сложно у тебя возникли при состовлении этого запроса? привиди пример своего запроса, который не работает

Comment: @SeniorPomidor SELECT * FROM products pr LEFT JOIN categories pc ON (pc.product_id = '$product_id') GROUP BY pc.category_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4 --- в данном случае выводит тот же самый исходный продукт

Comment: @SeniorPomidor попробовал в такой же конструкции RIGHT JOIN - выводит тупо 4 любых продукта, независимо от рубрики)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p, categories c1, categories c2
WHERE c2.product_id = $product_id
  AND c1.category_id = c2.category_id 
/*  AND c1.product_id != $product_id */
  AND c1.product_id = p.product_id 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4
```

Комментарий - на случай, если в списке выводимых не должен быть исходный.